# group of automorphisms of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Please help me with answering this question:

Compute the group of automorphisms of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I tried to find the homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and itself. Then I ruled out the ones that are not onto. Then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any such automorphism must preserve the identity $(1,1)$. It also must permute the set of idempotents $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. Therefore, the only automorphisms are the identity and the map which switches coordinates.

Comment: Do these automorphisms form a group?

Comment: Of course. The coordinate switching automorphism, when composed with itself, is the identity automorphism and so the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more thing: how can we justify that switching coordinates is onto?

Comment: @Spock the kernel of such a map is obviously only the identity $(0,0)$ and so the map is injective.